# Angular 6. Http.get() маппинг json в model

Tags: c#, http, map, angular

По сути, у меня тотже вопрос что и здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256206/how-to-observable-map-collection-of-json-objects-with-different-property-names

Проблема в том что

```
reportsToT(query: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.searchUrl + '?query=' + query)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json().map(res => new ProductModel(res.Id, res.Name, res.Description)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

не работает. Выдает соответственно

```
src/app/search.service.ts(54,8): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.
src/app/search.service.ts(54,52): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'.
```

Так выглядят импорты

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Все что вычитал не помогает. Angular 6, "rxjs": "^6.0.0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

return this.http.get(this.searchUrl + '?query=' + query).pipe(
    map((res) => {
        return new ProductModel(res.Id, res.Name, res.Description);
    })
);
```

`rxjs >= 5.5` поддерживает `pipeable` операторы (в целях оптимизации), также еще с Angular 4 не нужно маппить в json (`res => res.json()`)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но сейчас проблема в том, res воспринимается как object и соответственно ругается на res.Id, res.Name, res.Description - что данне поля не содержаться в object

Comment: Указание типа помогло return this.http.get<ProductModel>. Теперь решаю другие вопросы) В частости, получение коллекции. А как в таком случае быть, если при ходит коллекция в ответе? Т.е. return this.http.get<ProductModel[]>

Comment: overthesanity, подскажите, что не так делаю? Сделал сервис как вы и написали. В компоненте использую как ...reportsToT('someQuery').subscribe(item => this.result = item); Но в итоге объект null

Comment: @Rans, значит ваш бекенд возвращает `null`, либо же, сразу вопрос, вы используете `HttpClient` или `Http`? что вы инжектите в ваш сервис?

Comment: в том и дело что с API все норм, а this.result на странице не появляется. Там использовал *ngIf. Буду пересматривать, может что упустил

Comment: @Rans, что вы инжектите в сервис?

Comment: HttpClient. Данные из Api приходят, в этом убедился выводом res в консоль. правда есть момент, про который я не сказал. Модели у меня разные, т.е. из API приходит более "богатая" модель, мне же нужны только указанные проперти. Влияет ли это как-то? C angular только начинаю знакомиться

Comment: @Injectable({ providerIn: 'root' })